# Differentiable approximation of the round() Matlab function

Tags: matlab, approximation, calculus

Could you possibly suggest a differentiable approximation for the `round` Matlab function?

The `round` function looks like this:

[image]

I would like a differentiable function which [closely] resembles the one in the figure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write the derivative using the [dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) - it's called 'dirac comb'.

Also you can write the round function as sum of the [Heaviside step functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

for both there are many approximations - just select a differentiable one.

Comment: For example cos(Pi*x)^100 looks like a (unnormalized) dirac comb, then http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=cos%28PI*x%29^100&random=false gives a primitive f(x), and (f(x)-f(0.5))/(f(1.5)-f(0.5)) gives quite a steep staircase.

Comment: Could you be more specific that what kind of dirac delta could be used?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: i almost always would pick the approximation as sum of gaussians. But it totally depends on your further workflow - a bad choice can make it really hard.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `y=x` is differentiable and, if you stand far enough back, looks exactly like your target function.  It does differ from `round` in that it maps reals to reals rather than reals to integers.

I don't think it makes sense to talk about the differentiability of functions from the reals to the integers for anything other than trivial functions such as `f(r) = 1 for all r in Reals`.

You can probably get something closer to the step function by a judicious choice of trigonometric function.  For example, this

[image]

is a plot of `sin(x)+x`.  If I had more time I could probably tweak it to pass through `(k,k)` for all integers `k`, but I haven't so I'll leave that to you or other passers-by.

Comment: To add to the answer you could actually add a triangle wave https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave to x. That way you could approach as close to the step function as you like.

Comment: Hmmm, the triangle wave is not differentiable at an infinite number of points, or at a finite number of points within any range.

Comment: True - wrote too quick :) . I meant you could add the Fourier transform of it to some order.

Comment: x - sin(2pi x)/(2pi)

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of your function is 1 almost everywhere. If possible merely use 1.

If you really need to make the function smooth, consider using a low-pass filter.

Comment: Like I said originally `y=x` if you look at it from a distance !